# How to programatically register Avro Schema in Kafka Schema Registry using Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-python

I put data and schema to kafka and schema registry with python.

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer

value_schema_str = """
    {
       "type":"record",
       "name":"myrecord",
       "fields":[
          {
             "name":"ID",
             "type":["null", "int"],
             "default":null
          }, {
             "name":"PRODUCT",
             "type":["null", "string"],
             "default":null
          }, {
             "name":"QUANTITY",
             "type":["null", "int"],
             "default":null
          }, {
             "name":"PRICE",
             "type":["null", "int"],
             "default":null
          }
       ]
    }
    """

key_schema_str = """
    {
       "type":"record",
       "name":"key_schema",
       "fields":[
          {
             "name":"ID",
             "type":"int"
          }
       ]
    }
    """

def delivery_report(err, msg):
    """ Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush(). """

    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    value_schema = avro.loads(value_schema_str)
    key_schema = avro.loads(key_schema_str)
    value = {"ID": 199 , "PRODUCT":"Yagiz Gulbahar", "QUANTITY":1453,"PRICE":61}
    key = {"ID": 199}

    avroProducer = AvroProducer({
        'bootstrap.servers': '10.0.0.0:9092',
        'on_delivery': delivery_report,
        'schema.registry.url': 'http://10.0.0.0:8081'
    }, default_key_schema=key_schema, default_value_schema=value_schema)

    avroProducer.produce(topic='ersin_test_2', key=key, value=value)
    avroProducer.flush()
```

Can  I put just schema without data?

Comment: If you have Confluent control Center you could do it from there. Or you could also try it through REST Proxy as described in [the Confluent Schema Registry Tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html).

Comment: I do not have control center, can I do it with python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also register a schema programatically using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/) or [`python-schema-registry-client`](https://github.com/marcosschroh/python-schema-registry-client/).

---

**Using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/)**

```
from confluent_kafka.avro import SchemaRegistryClient, Schema


schema_str = """
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "user",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "firstName", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "age",  "type": "int"}
        ]
    }
"""

avro_schema = Schema(schema_str, 'AVRO')
sr = SchemaRegistryClient("http://schema-registry-host:8081")    
_schema_id = client.register_schema("yourSubjectName", avro_schema)
```

---

**Using [`python-schema-registry-client`](https://github.com/marcosschroh/python-schema-registry-client/)**

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient, schema


schema_ = schema.AvroSchema({
    "type": "record",
    "name": "user",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "firstName", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "age",  "type": "int"}
    ]
})


my_schema = sr.register("yourSubjectName", schema_)
```

Comment: how did you give api keys while registering schema via confluent-kafka-python ? am getting unauthorized. I followed AvroProducer code in https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python